# MYSQL: SELECT 1 from table1 where Id = 1 vs SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table1 where Id = 1)

Tags: mysql

I want to check whether row exists or not in **table1**, Here the condition is on **Primary key** so want to check which of the query is best to use and why?

```
QUERY 1: SELECT 1 from table1 where Id = 1;
QUERY 2: SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table1 where Id = 1)
```

NOTE: Id is primary key here.

Thanks!!

Comment: They aren't equivalent. The second one will always return a row, the first one only if the searched record exists. Which behavior is needed is up to the context, so this question can hardly be answered in general.

Answer (score 0):

With my MySQL :

```sql
IF (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table1 where Id = 1)) THEN
    -- ...
END ID;
```

Or without the `IF`

```sql
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table1 where Id = 1) as 'Exists';
```

### Will show

```
 
+--------+
| Exists |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+

OR

+--------+
| Exists |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+
```